# normalise batch of images in numpy per channel

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy ndarray of shape [batch_size, width, height, num_channels] (they're not RGB images, but similar concept of 2D fields).

I'd like to normalise these images per channel. Is there a more numpy way of doing this than the below? Particularly what I don't like is the loops over channels, and I found it weird having to do np.min and np.max on a slice. Also this is hardcoded to only work on tensors with rank 4, how could it be adapted to have dynamic rank, or the channels on a dynamic axis?

```
def get_img_ch_min_max(imgs):
    '''return minimum and maximum for each channel of [batch, width, height, channels]'''
    if len(imgs.shape)==3: imgs = np.expand_dims(imgs, axis=-1)
    # iterate each channel
    ch_min = np.array([np.min(imgs[:,:,:,i]) for i in range(imgs.shape[-1])])
    ch_max = np.array([np.max(imgs[:,:,:,i]) for i in range(imgs.shape[-1])])
    return ch_min, ch_max


def normalise_per_channel(imgs):
    '''normalise batch of images per channel, [batch, width, height, channels]'''
    if len(imgs.shape)==3: imgs = np.expand_dims(imgs, axis=-1)
    ch_min, ch_max = get_img_ch_min_max(imgs)
    ch_range = ch_max - ch_min
    imgs_ret = np.copy(imgs)
    for i in range(imgs.shape[-1]): # iterate each channel
        if ch_range[i] > 0: # avoid divide by zero
            imgs_ret[:,:,:,i] = (imgs[:,:,:,i] - ch_min[i]) / ch_range[i]
    imgs_ret = np.squeeze(imgs_ret)
    return imgs_ret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my attempt to answer your question without having tested my solution on your data.

I think the key idea here is to use `numpy.amin()` (or `amax()`) and specify `axis` argument. This will help avoid the loop:

```
rank = 4
ch_mins = np.amin(imgs, axis=tuple(range(rank - 1)))
ch_maxs = np.amax(imgs, axis=tuple(range(rank - 1)))
ch_range = ch_max - ch_min
idx = np.where(ch_range == 0)
ch_mins[idx] = 0
ch_range[idx] = 1
imgs = (imgs - ch_mins) / ch_range
```

For "dynamic axis" situation, I would suggest that you use `newaxis` or `[None,:,None,etc.]` appropriately and (if necessary) use [`numpy.moveaxis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.moveaxis.html) or one of the similar functions.

Comment: Thx for the reply. I didn't realise that the axis parameter could have an array, that sounds like it should work. however I get an error: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index. (i'm using numpy v14)

Comment: ok it works if it's a tuple, thanks! (I'll tweak and accept your answer)

Comment: @memo Thank you for trying this and reporting the error. I fixed it in my last edit. Of course you can always specify axes manually as `(0, 1, 2)`.

Comment: @memo Did you try to edit my answer? A message popped up briefly and it was saying that there was an edit when I wanted to edit it. Please feel free to try again.

Comment: @memo I added a hint at the end on how to deal with "dynamic axis".

Comment: yes I had tried to edit your answer to correct the axis, but your edit is better thanks.